# sql - how to count rows in sub-query according main query items

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get a list like this:

```
StockPart.title | qtyAvailable
```

qtyAvailable is the SUM() of stockItems rows where stock_items.stock_part_id = stock_parts.id (main query)

By using something like this:

```
SELECT 
  stock_parts.id,
  stock_parts.title,
    COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT id FROM stock_items WHERE stock_part_id = <STOCK_PART_ID_HERE> ) AS qtyAvailable
FROM
  `stock_parts`,
  `stock_items`
WHERE 1
```

How can I relate the WHERE clause in the sub-query to the main query row?

Comment: Where is the `JOIN`?

Comment: do I need? I don't know

Comment: add your database schema in question.

Comment: Probably learning SQL syntax will be a good start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT sp.id
       , sp.title
       , COUNT(si.stock_part_id ) AS qtyAvailable
FROM stock_parts sp 
left JOIN stock_items si
ON si.stock_part_id = sp.stock_part_id
GROUP BY sp.id, sp.title;
```

[Here is a small demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=232aae278ae181706632c63f7022b3be)

Comment: it returns all rows but qtyAvailable is 1 when should be zero (when there's no SI entry)

Comment: Hi @anderlaini , thanks for the feedback, and now ?

Comment: Hi @anderlaini happy to help. I have added a small demo and changed count(si.id) into count(si.stock_part_id). Hope this is ok ? Also, if this was a correct answer to you you can accept the answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want:

```
SELECT sp.id, sp.title, COUNT(si.stock_part_id) AS qtyAvailable
FROM stock_parts sp LEFT JOIN
     stock_items si
     ON si.stock_part_id = sp.stock_part_id
GROUP BY sp.id, sp.title;
```

Comment: it only shows StockPart row when there's at least one StockItem row

Comment: @Akina trying but getting error at line 4 `'WHERE si.stock_part_id = sp.id
GROUP BY sp.id, sp.title LIMIT 0, 25'`

Comment: @anderlaini . . . That should be `ON`!